# Unspected behaviour using Shape geometric library inside axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, tikz-shape

I want to draw this inverted triangle.

[image]

For this, I used the library shades.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm}   %  Left  bottom right top
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,import,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, shapes.geometric}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Coordinate system
    \draw[line width=0.75pt,->] (-40mm,0) -- (15mm,0) node[below] {$X$}  coordinate(x axis);
    \draw[line width=0.75pt,->] (0,-5mm) -- (0,15mm) node[above] {$Z$} coordinate(y axis);
           % sea water level
    \draw[blue,x=1.57ex,y=1ex] (-30mm,0mm) sin (-28mm,2mm) cos (-26mm,0mm) sin (-24mm,-2mm) cos (-22mm,0mm);
    \node[blue,scale=0.5,anchor=south,isosceles triangle, draw, shape border uses incircle, shape border rotate=-90, node font=\itshape, label={above left:SWL}] at (-34mm,0mm) {};
    \draw[blue] (-36mm,-1mm)--(-32mm,-1mm);
    \draw[blue] (-35mm,-2mm)--(-33mm,-2mm);
    \draw[blue] (-34.5mm,-3mm)--(-33.5mm,-3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I get the desired shape.
[image]

However, when I add an axis environment to add the sine wave. The same piece of code is no longer working. I am having some issues regarding the coordinate system.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm}   %  Left  bottom right top
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,import,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, shapes.geometric}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5,
            xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, axis lines=center]
    %Sine wave
    \addplot[blue, domain=-4:4]  {sin(deg (x))};
    % Ground
     \draw(axis cs: -4,-4.5)--(axis cs: 4,-4.5);
     % sea water level
    \node[blue,scale=0.5,anchor=south,isosceles triangle, draw, shape border uses incircle, shape border rotate=-90, node font=\itshape, label={above left:SWL}] (axis cs: -3cm,0cm) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I get just half triangle, and no found the way how the coordinates works, because I am not able to move it where it should be.

Any help/guidance is welcome.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a pgfplots user. I created an abscissa axis function domain between -6 and -4, pos=[0.5] gives the middle to place the triangle.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644949/unspected-behaviour-using-shape-geometric-library-inside-axis-environment
    \standaloneconfig{border=5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm}   %  Left  bottom right top
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections, shapes.geometric}%
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
    \begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-7, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5,
                %xtick=\empty,
                ytick=\empty, axis lines=center]
        %Sine wave
        \addplot[blue, domain=-4:4]  {sin(deg (x))};
        \addplot[domain=-6:-4]  {0}
        coordinate [pos=0.5](A);% the middle 
        %sea water level
        \node[blue,scale=0.5,anchor=south,isosceles triangle, draw, shape border uses incircle, shape border rotate=-90, node font=\itshape, label={above left:SWL}] at (A) {};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
Based on your solution, I tried other options, and it looks that defining just the coordinate (no need for the additional \addplot) is enough. It did work! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, for the other user and me, it would be interesting to post your answer.